# Why does this return None?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm testing out [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3) (running Python 3.5.1) and I noticed that after every line of input into the console, the console replies with `None`. I'm not using any fancy definitions with forgotten return values, this happens even after assignment statements. What is going on here?

Example:

```
x,y,z=1,2,3
=> None
print(x+y+z)
6
=> None
```

Comment: Statements don't return anything, `print` function returns `None`.

Comment: Your code does exactly as is, type each line in an interpreter and press enter and that's exactly what it should do. Try this after you did x,y,z = 1,2,3 then just type x and enter then y and enter and z and enter you should see 1 then 2 then 3

Comment: @Andy It doesn't have much to do with repl.it, beside the fact that the website always prints whatever the statement returns and the default behaviour of the normal REPL is not to print anything if the return value is None.

Comment: Let's put it the other way around: what would you *expect* it to do differently?

Comment: On my local interpreter, the print statement would output only the printed value, and not give me a return at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None is the default return value of statements that do not have a return value. Some interpreter shells display it, some don't.

It's perfectly normal, don't worry about it.